# Multiple errors when updating

Tags: apt, updates

All of a sudden without any intervention from myself, my server suddenly stopped processing emails.

Using Ubuntu 22.04.

When I attempt to update I get the following errors:

```
user@mail:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.IKXbKx for passing config to apt-key
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:4 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.3t2NAg for passing config to apt-key
Err:6 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-updates_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0755 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.o6rjJv - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.tW8m77 - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.zqqC2m - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.ODvfCF - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.IKXbKx for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-updates_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-backports_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-backports_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-backports_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-backports_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-backports_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.3t2NAg for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-updates_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
E: The repository 'http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
user@mail:~$
```

I also tried to upgrade and get the following:

```
user@mail:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-virtual python3-update-manager update-manager-core
The following packages will be upgraded:
  clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam clamdscan libclamav9 libclamunrar9 qemu-guest-agent
8 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 1780 kB of archives.
After this operation, 78.8 kB disk space will be freed.
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0755 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated. I dont really want to have to reinstall everything from scratch as its a mailserver and takes a few days to complete.

Also, this is the snapshot version so cant restore and get anything better than this install.

Many thanks.

**ADDITION:**
I ran this command and rebooted and it seems to be fixed. But this terrified me. I dont really understand what occured, possible similar to windows dik errors. But this is more worrying when on a mail server. Any further advice welcome. Heres what solved it:

```
user@mail:~$ sudo fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
cloudimg-rootfs: recovering journal
cloudimg-rootfs contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 528 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 2083 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 2103 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 2200 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 2208 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3070, i_blocks is 3752, should be 3760.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  +7831908
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #239 (14887, counted=14886).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #430 (23597, counted=23596).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong (18247366, counted=18281663).
Fix<y>? yes
Inode bitmap differences:  -528 -2083 -2103 -2200 -2208
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #0 (395, counted=400).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong (10185489, counted=10185110).
Fix ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes

cloudimg-rootfs: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
cloudimg-rootfs: ***** REBOOT SYSTEM *****
cloudimg-rootfs: 136810/10321920 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 2661436/20943099 blocks
```